# Show/hide a image & radio button when it is checked and unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im working on a logic, where if I check the radio button the radio button should hide and an icon should display and this has to be over a three radio buttons.

My condition is there are three radio buttons which are 'Approved' & 'Declined' & 'Waitlisted'. When i check radio button 'Approved' an image shld be visible and that 'Approved' radio button should be hidden, then when i check other button this 'Approved'radio should show and image should hide. so this has to work with all three radio buttons.

Any ideas?

Comment: post your code here, don't paste your logic.

Answer (score -1):

Approved



     Declined



     Waitlisted

```js
function ShowHideImage(id)
 {
  $('.ImageShow').each(function(){
   $(this).hide();
  });
  $('#Image'+id).show();
  var RadioClass = $('#'+id).attr('class');
  $('.'+RadioClass).each(function(){
   $(this).parent().show();
  });
  $('.'+id).hide();
 }

 $(document).on('click','.RadioButton',function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  ShowHideImage(id);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="images/final_fantasy.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" style="display: none;" class="ImageShow" id="ImageRadioApproved" alt="image1">
<img src="images/Koala.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" style="display: none;" class="ImageShow" id="ImageRadioDeclined" alt="image2">
<img src="images/Desert.jpg" width="150px" height="150px" style="display: none;" class="ImageShow" id="ImageRadioWaitlisted" alt="image3">

<div class="RadioApproved">
  <input type="radio" class="RadioButton" id="RadioApproved" name="RadioSelect"> Approved
</div>
<div class="RadioDeclined">
  <input type="radio" class="RadioButton" id="RadioDeclined" name="RadioSelect"> Declined
</div>
<div class="RadioWaitlisted">
  <input type="radio" class="RadioButton" id="RadioWaitlisted" name="RadioSelect"> Waitlisted
</div>
```

Comment: I actually have three different icons / images for three buttons, but by giving one id will reflect only that image right and actually i have switch case function written and given as onclick to input.

Comment: I have made some changes in the code. Hope this will help you.

Comment: im new to JavaScript & Jqurey thats why had to ask in detail...any way thanq very much yogendrasin

Comment: Welcome Kishore. You may ask in details, we all are here to answer in details for any question that will help to find the result.